# Is it possible to work on the same project in Visual Studio from several places online?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I would like to be able to do a collaborative work in Visual Studio. For now I know only how to create and access the project off-line. Is it possible to work on a project on-line?

Comment: @scopchanov That's one hell of an edit. You basically turned this question from bad to workable. Still makes me wonder isn't that just a software question? If you don't mind your code being public just use Github! You can also store your code on a server. It seems to be more about architecture

Comment: @5th, :) You are right. I tried to salvage it by turning it into something meaningful, because it is otherwise legit question, since it _directly involves programming tools_.

Comment: Alrighty. Learnt something here and retracted my flag :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a version control system, like GitHub. Visual Studio is already integrated to work with GitHub or other VCSs.